# Python - Minimizing Chi-squared

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, minimization, chi-squared

I have been trying to fit a linear model to a set of stress/strain data by minimizing chi-squared. Unfortunately using the code below is not correctly minimizing the `chisqfunc` function. It is finding the minimum at the initial conditions, `x0`, which is not correct. I have looked through the `scipy.optimize` documentation and tested minimizing other functions which has worked correctly. Could you please suggest how to fix the code below or suggest another method I can use to fit a linear model to data by minimizing chi-squared?

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as opt

filename = 'data.csv'

data = numpy.loadtxt(open(filename,"r"),delimiter=",")

stress = data[:,0]
strain = data[:,1]
err_stress = data[:,2]

def chisqfunc((a, b)):
    model = a + b*strain
    chisq = numpy.sum(((stress - model)/err_stress)**2)
    return chisq

x0 = numpy.array([0,0])

result =  opt.minimize(chisqfunc, x0)
print result
```

Thank you for reading my question and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, Will

EDIT: Data set I am currently using: [Link to data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YR_XKF3wtmYl9pNHJHWEZFU3M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The code looks fine to me, and provides good results on some mock data I created on my machine. Just one note: is your variable `err_stress` the uncertainty in the measured stress for different values of deformation correct?

Comment: one trivial point: you're checking the result with `print result.x` right? minimize does NOT update `x0`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I did use `print result.x`. Yes `err_stress` is an array of errors for the array of measured stresses.

Comment: What are `result.success` and `result.status` after calling `minimize`?

Comment: `result.success` is `True`, `result.status` is 0 and `result.x` is `[0 0]`. Thanks for the assistance Warren.

Comment: @flebool , I have uploaded a the set of data that I'm currently using: [Link to data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YR_XKF3wtmYl9pNHJHWEZFU3M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your initial guess is very far from the actual solution. If you add a print statement inside `chisqfunc()` like `print (a,b)`, and rerun your code, you'll get something like:

```
(0, 0)
(1.4901161193847656e-08, 0.0)
(0.0, 1.4901161193847656e-08)
```

This means that `minimize` evaluates the function only at these points.

if you now try to evaluate `chisqfunc()` at these 3 pairs of values, you'll see that they EXACTLY match, for example

```
print chisqfunc((0,0))==chisqfunc((1.4901161193847656e-08,0))
True
```

This happens because of rounding floating points arithmetics. In other words, when evaluating `stress - model`, the var `stress` is too many order of magnitude larger than `model`, and the result is truncated.

One could then just try bruteforcing it, increasing floating point precision, with writing `data=data.astype(np.float128)` just after loading the data with `loadtxt`. `minimize` fails, with `result.success=False`, but with a helpful message

> Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.

One possibility is then to provide a better initial guess, so that in the subtraction `stress - model` the `model` part is of the same order of magnitude, the other to rescale the data, so that the solution will be closer to your initial guess `(0,0)`.

It is **MUCH** better if you just rescale the data, making for example nondimensional with respect to a certain stress value (like the yelding/cracking of this material)

This is an example of the fitting, using as a stress scale the maximum measured stress. There are very few changes from your code:

```
import numpy
import scipy.optimize as opt

filename = 'data.csv'

data = numpy.loadtxt(open(filename,"r"),delimiter=",")

stress = data[:,0]
strain = data[:,1]
err_stress = data[:,2]


smax = stress.max()
stress = stress/smax
#I am assuming the errors err_stress are in the same units of stress.
err_stress = err_stress/smax

def chisqfunc((a, b)):
    model = a + b*strain
    chisq = numpy.sum(((stress - model)/err_stress)**2)
    return chisq

x0 = numpy.array([0,0])

result =  opt.minimize(chisqfunc, x0)
print result
assert result.success==True
a,b=result.x*smax
plot(strain,stress*smax)
plot(strain,a+b*strain)
```

Your linear model is quite good, i.e. your material has a very linear behaviour for this range of deformation (what material is it anyway?):
[image]

Comment: Ahh, I tried using the results of `stats.linregress` as the initial conditions which also didn't work unfortunately. I think the reason it  didn't work is because the stress values are so large not much change in `chisqfunc` is experienced with small change in `x0`. Rescaling using `smax` worked a treat. Thank you very much for your help on this.  This data is a sample of a data set (linear section only) for the extension of a Cu98%/Be2% wire.